# How can i check the radiobutton that it has been checked in this table?

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code,

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="invited_table" style="height:300px;overflow:auto;width: 700px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="invited_table_selectall">
            </th><th style="display:none;">User ID</th><th>Classify</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Moderator</th><th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="invited_table_body">
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none">1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Member</td>

            <td>Administrator</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>barbie.admin@access-company.com</td>
            <td>
            <input type="radio" name="invited_radio_btn" checked="checked">
            </td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="internal_case">
            </td><td style="display:none;">115</td><td>Member</td><td>test003</td><td>test003</td><td>test003@com</td><td>
            <input type="radio" name="invited_radio_btn">
            </td><td>
            <button id="invited_delete_btn">
                delete
            </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="internal_case">
            </td><td style="display:none;">116</td><td>Member</td><td>test004</td><td>test004</td><td>test004@com</td><td>
            <input type="radio" name="invited_radio_btn">
            </td><td>
            <button id="invited_delete_btn">
                delete
            </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="internal_case">
            </td><td style="display:none;">0</td><td>non</td><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td><td></td><td>
            <button id="invited_delete_btn">
                delete
            </button></td><td style="display:none;">Etc/GMT+13</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the event handler,

```
$("#create_room_btn").click(function(){
            $("#invited_table tr").each(function() {

                $(this).find('td').each(function(index, obj) {
                                                //console.log($(this).find('input').prop("checked",true));
                    console.log(obj.innerHTML);

                 });
                // temp paused
                            });
        });
```

I googled that i have to use $.prop or $.attr, but i'm not getting the result i want.

I need a true or false return to validate the radiobutton has been checked or not.

Any good Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a **true or false** return to validate the radiobutton has been
> checked or not.

Seems like you looking for a boolean expression.

You might want to use [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for this, which returns true if it is checked and false when not checked:

```
$('.check').each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));  
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        //what to do with checked checkbox
    }
})
```

*This is a example*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6gZ7/)

Where the first checkbox returns true and the second one false.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, i got the goal i want using $.is :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use each here and traverse the table. Use `:radio:checked` to get the checked radio button. You also need to put forward slash to close the most of input tags.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/B8b3H/)**

```
var checkedRadioCollection = $('#invited_table :radio:checked');
```

If you want to check how many checked radio you have

```
var checkRadioCount = $('#invited_table :radio:checked').length;
```

To check if you have any of radio check in condition

```
if($('#invited_table :radio:checked').length)
{

}
```

Comment: You also have to fix html, Check my updated answer with live demo.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$('#radio_button :checked').live('change',function(){
alert('Something is checked.');
});
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("input:radio[name='yourRadioName']").is(":checked")) {
      //its checked
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#create_room_btn").click(function () {
    $("#invited_table tr").each(function () {

        $(this).find('td').each(function (index, obj) {
            if ($(this).find('input').attr("type") == "radio")
                console.log($(this).find('input').is(":checked"));

        });

    });
});
```

Every this perfect in your code u try some what.k try this code u ll get true false

check : http://jsfiddle.net/xz7nV/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#invited_table :radio:checked').length)
{
    // checked
}else{
    // not checked
}
```